# jQuery Date Picker not working on Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui

I've a jQuery UI Calendar as below and it works on IE only not on Chrome:

```
<input type="image" src="/images/caleder.jpg" id="btnCalendar" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#btnPeriodCal").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

If I change `type="text"` it seems to work. Could someone please help me with how to resolve the above issue. I can't use `type="text"` as I need to show the image.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the `buttonImage` property. Check out my answer. :)

Answer (score 13):

I have a sample problem with date picker.

I used date picker and it worked fine in Firefox and IE but not in chrome. I can see the calender when I click the input field. I selected the date but the date values are not entering in input field.

I don't have option so I changed `type='text'` then it works in chrome..

[image: Input type is date]

[image: Input type is text]

Comment: Naveen Thanks for your feedback..Because of that i checked my friend's work. He also used 

datepicker which doesn't have close button in calender. I changed his codes, input type to date 

and checked in chrome..It works. Date values are entered in field.

We both downloaded the date picker from internet. May be there is some difference in that. But I 

am getting the values if I only set type is text. I don't have problem with that because I did 

Javascript and PHP validation for my date values.

Comment: but the post is tagged jquery ui datepicker... :)

Comment: yes the Post is jquery ui datepicker..Actually i don't know about ui and all..I had the same problem, searched the internet found this post. But this post and my issue having some common issues. I thought it will help others if i share my exp..

Answer (score 4):

You can use a handler:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope this works! :)

Comment: Did not work, Should i keep this line as it is or change to <input type="image" src="/images/caleder.jpg" id="btnCalendar" />

Comment: Note I must be able to display calendar icon for users to click on.

Comment: Yeah, that is what this does. There will be a text box with the icon you specify. Check out this example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/icon-trigger.html

Comment: Does DataPicker must have associated TextBox?

Comment: Yes! That's the basic requirement of jQuery UI DP. What you wanna associate with?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And I thought why input could work, but button could not. The trick is that input gets focus when clicked, button doesn't. Try this:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnPeriodCal").datepicker().click(function () { $(this).focus(); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am wrong only div tags, span tags, etc.. can be date pickers.

Answer (score 0):

Use it as -

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>

$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

Check it in action - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger

And don't forget to include these files in `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/jquery-ui.min.js">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue: I wanted my datepicker to appear when a link was clicked, and have no  field (or rather a hidden field). (My use-case was that the date on the calendar was to be used to find a range of dates up to and including that datepicker selection, so I don't need the actual date value except to be passed to the onSelect handler.)

So this works in Firefox:

```
<a ...>click for calendar:   <input type="hidden" value="" />  </a>
```

but not in Chrome. Replacing the  with:

```
<input type="text" value="" style="display: none" />
```

also failed. I ended up with this:

```
<input  type="text" value="" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0" />
```

though I'm not proud of it!

Answer (score 0):

I spent 3 hours trying to figure it out this problem, and this is the way that I solved the problem.

use the following lines as your libraries.

```
    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.10/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and this is the javascript used to fix the problem:

```
$(function() {
    $("#date_of_birth_date").datepicker({ 
        maxDate: '+0', changeYear: true, yearRange: "-70:+0" 
    });
});
```

remember to remove all the previous libraries etc